# Rails - Unique id per model, not whole database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model and a Book model. A book belongs to a user and a user has many books.

In the view, I'm showing all the books a user has created in the user show view by doing

```
<% @user.books.each do |book| %>
  <%= book.id %> 
  <%= book.title %>
<% end %>
```

But the `book.id` has a number that's unique to ALL the books in the database, not just per user. I want this id to be unique to the user, so if there's 1,000 books in the database and the user only has 3 of those books, it will show the ids as 1, 2 and 3 (instead of like 476, 239, 105, etc.).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's just for display purposes, why not just add a counter like so:

```
<% count = 1 %>
<% @user.books.each do |book| %>
  <%= count %>
  <% count += 1 %>      
  <%= book.title %>
<% end %>
```

So instead of book.id, you would have <%= count %>

If you want to flip it around and start with the latest, then this would work:

```
<% count = @user.books.length %>
<% @user.books.each do |book| %>
  <%= count %>
  <% count -= 1 %>      
  <%= book.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Great thanks! It is mainly for display purposes, so this works. But now I've added ```<% @user.books.order("created_at DESC").each do |book| %>``` so that the latest are at the top and would like the numbering to be flipped around too. Is that possible with this method?

Comment: Hey one other quick question: How would I go about writing an if statement that says "if it's the latest book added...do this"?

Comment: inside the each block:  if count == @user.books.length

Comment: FWIW you can use [#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) instead of introducing the count variable.

Answer (score 1):

you can do several things... the fastest way is to include a counter before the loop and increment it... if you just need unique numbers per book...

If you really need ids you can add a separate field to your books table and handle the id numbers by calculating them in your model...

another way is to add another model like user_books and build a has many through association that includes the counter field, check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think I'll create a new model only as a last resort. Just trying to do this rather quickly and it's mainly for display purposes. Thanks!